# How to convert String to Enum with an annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, enums, annotations

I want to create an annotation that converts String to my Enum object. I have a DTO object that gets a String field named type as request body. Here I want to take that `String and covert it to my Enum` object with a custom `annotation`.

Enum object:

```
public enum Type {

    MOVIE_CAPABLE,
    SERIES_CAPABLE,
    MOVIE_SERIES_CAPABLE
}
```

DTO object:

```
@Data
public class ProviderRequest {

    @ConvertToEnum
    private Type type;

    // Other stuff
}
```

I know that it will work with uppercase String like `MOVIE_CAPABLE` without any kind of converting but I want to be able to send lowercase string too.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to create a new custom `@ConvertToEnum` annotation?  Also, what do you mean about uppercase "working" but not lowercase?

Comment: Yes. I mean if you send lowercase String in request, it does not convert to Enum unless you use "Type.valueOf("movie_capable".toUpperCase())".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can use `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on top of `private Type type;`

Here is the full working implementation.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProviderRequest implements Serializable {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EnumTypeDeserializer.class)
    private Type type;
    // Other stuff
}
```

```
public class EnumTypeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Type> {

    @Override
    public Type deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        final ObjectCodec objectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec();
        final JsonNode node = objectCodec.readTree(jsonParser);
        final String type = node.asText();
        return Type.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```